# gd2 library is not giving good results

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, gdlib

I am using gd2 library to cut images but it is not working for my images.

I am uploading images of 1000X1000px and then cut it in 300X300 and 107X84.

300X300 image is fine but 107X84 image isn't great. I can easily see the difference with same image cut using photoshop of same size.

[image]  **(gd2 image)**

[image] **(photoshop image)**

You can see difference of both the images.

I am using the following code

```
//small image
$config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
$config['source_image'] = 'uploads/images/medium/'.$upload_data['file_name'];
$config['new_image']    = 'uploads/images/small/'.$upload_data['file_name'];
$config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
$config['width'] = 107;/*235*/
$config['height'] = 84;/*235*/
$this->image_lib->initialize($config); 
$this->image_lib->resize();
$this->image_lib->clear();
```

Comment: Make use of imagemagick instead of GD library function

Comment: what gd interface is this? php gd is not object based. but if your lib's naming parallels gd's, you probably want `resample()`, not `resize()`.

Comment: `$config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;` is pressed you image.

Comment: @YatinTrivedi I dont have imagemagick installed.

Comment: @Girish I made it false because I need the same size

Comment: then image will be stretched.

Comment: what can be the solution

Comment: you should crop and resize to your required `dim`

Comment: @Girish how to do that Please tell me